# Blackfire profiling error - exit status 60

Tags: blackfire

I am running a vagrant box with Centos 7 as its OS. I installed blackfire without error and then tried to profile from the web browser. It started profile, but then just hung and hung and never finished. I then tried it via curl in the command line and got the following error:

```
$ blackfire curl https://gitlist.demo.blackfire.io/
Profiling: [####------------------------------------] 1/10
Error while running command: exit status 60
Use the option '--ignore-exit-status' to ignore command exit status
* About to connect() to gitlist.demo.blackfire.io port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.76.137.79...
* Connected to gitlist.demo.blackfire.io (54.76.137.79) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=gitlist.demo.blackfire.io
*   start date: Jul 07 14:09:16 2019 GMT
*   expire date: Oct 05 14:09:16 2019 GMT
*   common name: gitlist.demo.blackfire.io
*   issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
* NSS error -8181 (SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE)
* Peer's Certificate has expired.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate has expired.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a 
"bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Can someone explain to me what this error is? I have used Blackfire successfully on other projects (albeit, those were Ubuntu boxes) and have never seen this error. I can't find much on the web about this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cURL is not sending the HTTP request because the "Peer's Certificate has expired".
As suggested, you could have added the "--insecure" option.

But it seems the certificate has been renewed.

Comment: Can you explain to what the Peers certificate is and why/when it might expire?

Comment: The HTTPS certificate of "gitlist.demo.blackfire.io" was expired. So curl was not able to validate that the connection was safe.

Comment: hmm, thats odd. Because I first tried to curl my own site name and had the same error, and only afterwords tried this one...